# ¿Como puedo insertar un archivo HTML que tiene una biblioteca de documentos de respaldo de información en SharePoint en la nube?

Tags: sharepoint-online

tengo un archivo html que es de aplicación de industryprint version 2004 y el mismo genera una biblioteca de documento cuando lo guardo en formato html, ahora lo que necesito es insertar ese archivo html en sharepoint en la nube.
espero me puedan ayudar.
saludos